# jQuery / How to define the next element with class XY and change its display to "true" using click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a wiki page and would like to achieve the following:

I have two divs wrapped in a wrapper. The first one will be the container for the keyword and the second one will be the container for the description of the keyword. By default the second one is hidden and should pop up once the user clicks on the keyword. I tried to set up some javascript but nothing happens whenever I click the keyword div.

Any solutions to this?

Thank you very much in advance!

```js
$(".Keyword").click(function() {
  $(".Keyword").next(".Content").attr("display: true;");
});
```

```css
.listWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.Keyword {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.Keyword:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

<div class="listWrapper">

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the css to (`.css('display', 'block')`) or (`.toggle()`) the `. Content`, which is next to the clicked `.Keyword` (`$(this)`):

```js
$(".Keyword").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".Content").toggle();
});
```

```css
.listWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.Keyword {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.Keyword:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

<div class="listWrapper">

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! One more additional question. Is there a way to make it like toggle? That it will be hidden again on second mouse click? Or do I need a separate function for that?

Comment: You can use `.toggle()` to show/hide. See updated answer.

Comment: What if the *next* element could be *anywhere* in the page, not necessarily a sibling?

Comment: You'll need to "connect" them somehow. It can be the relative index in the other container, a shared data modal, shared class names, for attributes, ids, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use toggle(). 
Show if an element is hidden. Hide if an element is visible

```js
$(".Keyword").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".Content").toggle();
});
```

```css
.listWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.Keyword {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.Keyword:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

<div class="listWrapper">

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="keyPairWrapper">
    <div class="Keyword">Click me to show my content</div>
    <div class="Content">This is the content for Key1</div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few errors in your javascript:

- use `$(this)` instead of `$(".Keyword")` to refer to the clicked element, and not *all .Keyword elements*
- `display: true` is not valid, you need to use `display: block`
- `.attr("display: true;")` is invalid, you're changing CSS, not attributes, so use `.css('display', 'block')`, or better `.show()` or `.toggle()`

```js
$(".Keyword").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".Content").show();
});
```